# Convert integer to string on bidirectional binding

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-template

In the project I am working on, have a dropdown field component which is being used for all the dropdown fields thorough out the application.

The component has an `@input options` which gets the options for the dropdown in this format `[{value: '', label: ''},.. ]`

This works with most of my dropdowns , but for one, the value comes as integer. As '2' !== 2 , the dropdown cant display the value.

```
<mat-select class="form-control" [(value)]="value">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{option.label}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

There is a similar issue reported on [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7771#issuecomment-336482394).

As this comment, I can have have a work around for this by having input and output separately.

```
<mat-select class="form-control" [value]="value.toString()" (change)="value = $event.value">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{option.label}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But I wonder, anyone have a nice solution for this problem.

Many Thanks,

Notes: (Pls don't suggest to change the value to integer type, as this will affect other dropdowns which has uuid etc as value)

Answer (score 0):

```
[value]="option.value"
```

Convert it to

```
[value]="{{option.value}}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work and cause error.

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0

Even using value="{{option.value}}" doesn't work